# Best Approach For Setting ETAG Value for a JSON Resource

Tags: scala, playframework

I am not sure on what is the best approach and how to set the ETAG value for a JSON resource  when using the Scala Playframework.

My use case is as follows: I have a service which will GET the resource and display it in the user's browser. On any subsequent PUT action, I want to check if that resource has changed in the backend.

My question is when I get the JSON resource, what is the idiomatic way to calculate the hash and set the etag value for the JSON representation that is served. Is it simply retrieve the JSON resource, calculate the hash, set the header and serve the resource or does Play provide any utilities to do this or is there a sbt plugin which can do this?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your specific question, but ETags are discussed in the Play documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsOverview#Etag-support).

Comment: Yes I saw that but it's more for the web assets rather my use case. Also as usual the Play documentation is not very helpful and doesn't really go into detail on how to use the sbt-digest plugin

Answer (score 1):

Play provides [`Cached`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/066a07d1c62de47fc8e8bcf36a2d89831f44594e/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cached.scala#L24) class to add caching to an `Action`. Here is example usage:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api.cache.{Cached, CachedBuilder}
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, cached: Cached)(implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  val cacheOk: CachedBuilder =
    cached.status((req: RequestHeader) => "someKey", OK, 5.minutes)

  def index: EssentialAction = cacheOk { Action {
      Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
  }
}
```

`Cached` will add [`ETag`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/066a07d1c62de47fc8e8bcf36a2d89831f44594e/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cached.scala#L209) and handle [`If-None-Match`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/066a07d1c62de47fc8e8bcf36a2d89831f44594e/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cached.scala#L157). However, it sets the hash of [expiration date](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/066a07d1c62de47fc8e8bcf36a2d89831f44594e/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cached.scala#L207) as `ETag`:

```
val etag = s""""${Codecs.sha1(expirationDate)}""""
val resultWithHeaders = result.withHeaders(ETAG -> etag, EXPIRES -> expirationDate)
```

I am not aware Play provides out-of-the-box `ETag` as hash of JSON, however it seems possible to implement a similar class on the basis of `Cached` with [`handleResult`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/066a07d1c62de47fc8e8bcf36a2d89831f44594e/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cached.scala#L199) modified to hash JSON body of `Result`.